# How to validate a path stored in a property in Windows installer XML (WIX)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wix, codeplex

Is there a way to validate an installation path for a custom property defined by the user ? In **WIXUI_Advanced** user interface, following statement exists to validate the install path for **WIXUI_INSTALLDIR** property.

```
<Publish Dialog="Dialog_Name" Control="InstallScopeNext" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="9"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
```

Is there a way to validate other user defined properties that we use to store installation paths as well ? as an example I want to validate my own defined property as following.

```
  <Publish Dialog="Dialog_Name" Control="InstallScopeNext" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="9"><![CDATA[MYOWN_INSTALLDIRECTORY_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
```

Code examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. **WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID** can only be used to validate a path which is stored in side **WIXUI_INSTALLDIR** property only. So at the time we define a install path, best to save the installation path in **WIXUI_INSTALLDIR** property and our own defined property.

```
 <Property Id="INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
 <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
```

Since validating installation path can only be validated for **WIXUI_INSTALLDIR** property, fields will not cause any harm storing in two properties.

Comment: It should be noted that `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR` works indirect. It's value needs to be the name of the property which contains the path (not the path itself).